# When, or should I use builder pattern on jpa entities？

Tags: java, spring, jpa, copy-constructor, builder

I'm new to web developing so this may be a dumb question.

when dealing with complex entities that have both mandatory and optional fields, the first thing comes to my mind was using builder pattern. For example a User entity like this:

```java
public class User {

    // mandatory fields
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String emailAddress;

    // optional fields
    private Gender gender
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private String description;
    private Integer points;

    // getter / setters etc
}
```

After some modification, the builder pattern works fine and offers much clear code when creating a User.

However, when I (almost) finished my tutorial project, I find that the only place I need to create a User is in the userService, where I can use a copy constructor like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserService {

    @PostMapping(path = "/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {

        User newUser = new User(user);
        newUser = userRepository.save(newUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The builder pattern becomes meaningless under this circumstance. But I can still find some articles discuss about "builder pattern for jpa entities"

My question is
1. when creating entities from post request, is it best practice to use copy-constructor, over the builder pattern?
2. when to use the builder pattern on jpa entities?

Comment: IIRC to use JPA entities, you need a non-argument constructor and getters and setters anyway, so the only thing a builder gives you is convenience in creating an instance (and not additional consistency checks).

Comment: @daniu agree that builder pattern is only for convenience, but it is more convenient to use copy-constructors, so is it ok to say that builder pattern is meaningless in JPA entities?

Comment: The builder pattern is especially useful when building immutable objects. Since JPA entities are normally not immutable, in my opinion there is not much benefit in creating builders for all your JPA entities.

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you feel you need to make a copy of the user? What's wrong with the `user` your method receives as a parameter?

Comment: @crizzis sorry I missed one line that persists the user. cause I have a OneToOne profile class for the user, if I save the user from the param directly the profile is not attached to the user and it runs into error. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly though.

Comment: @edwardlol-zhou In your case, it's not really useful to have a builder for an entity.
However, it's not considered a good practice to use entities as DTOs/Controller parameters. The controller in your example should use a UserDto as a param (which may or may not have all the fields that are in your User entity). If you do this, you will need to write a converter/service method to create an User entity from your UserDto parameter and here, it's really convenient to use a builder to create your entity, instead of setting all fields through setters.